# Windows 8 login not working on shared folder using Ubuntu with SAMBA

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, samba, workgroup

I have a computer acting as a local web development server using Ubuntu 12 with the desktop GUI.  I am using SAMBA to share a folder in `/var/www` (i know this is not advised but it is sharing and this is local, I also changed the owner to user chad).  I install samba on the ubuntu and I can see the folder but I cannot connect to the folder.  Here is a copy of my `smb.conf` and also here are the things I tried:

1. Created the shared folder using the samba gui server administration.
2. Assigned the user to the folder and set the username/password
3. Originally I just used *workgroup* and I figured that would work but did not.  I then tried to change the workgroup name to `s1domain` and use it instead.

The problems is when I try to connect from Windows 8 it prompts me with a login.  I have tried the following combinations:

- s1\chad
- s1domain\chad
- workgroup\chad
- chad

I am confused because when the prompt first comes up it has my comptuer name.  What workgroup and domain am I suppose to use?  I had this actually work one time then randomly stopped working.  Also this works if I open the share to everyone.

SMB.CONF:

```
workgroup = s1domain

    [www2]
        path = /var/www
        writeable = yes
    ;   browseable = yes
        valid users = chad
```

Answer (score 0):

Could use a bit more info from your smb.conf. If that's really the only line in [global] maybe the output of 'testparm -sv' would help (and please no commented lines).

And is "chad" a valid samba user (did you add him to Samba with smbpasswd)?